# Image segmentation on the edge (no pun entended)

Tags: segmentation

I want to detect nuclei from unevenly stained images, which works quite well with `LocalAdaptiveBinarize`. Unfortunately, in many of these images the imaged area does not cover the whole image due to irregular tissue edges:

```
img = Import["https://i.imgur.com/viITElm.png"]
```

[image]

```
mask = Import["https://i.imgur.com/zTLwVpM.png"]
```

[image]

Using `LocalAdaptiveBinarize` the nuclei within the imaged area and at the image borders are properly segmented. Segmentation goes wrong near the tissue edges, which is clear since the algorithm takes all values of `0.0` (the actual background) into account:

```
seg = LocalAdaptiveBinarize[img, 50, {1.35, 0.15, 0}]
```

[image]

Is there a way to exclude the background values of `0.0` for LocalAdaptiveBinarize?